# Simple regex to match some characters and exclude others

Tags: php, regex, character

I need a regex for preg_match to accept all alphanumeric characters except `l`, `L`, `v`, `V`, `0`, `2`.

I've tried

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][^lLvV02]*$
```

It works good excluding lLvV02 but it also accept other characters like SPACE,ù,@,#, etc...

How should I change it?

Comment: Use `^(?:(?![lLvV02])[a-zA-Z0-9])*$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?:(?![lLvV02])[a-zA-Z0-9])*$
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group

  - `(?![lLvV02])[a-zA-Z0-9]` - an alnum char that is not one of the chars inside the character class residing inside a negative lookahead
- `)*` - end of the non-capturing group, 0 or more repetitions
- `$` - end of string

See the [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3F%3A(%3F!%5BlLvV02%5D)%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D)*%24):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for a Regex, but you can test for alphanumeric first and only if that passes check that the others are NOT present:

```
if(ctype_alnum($string) && !preg_match('/[lLvV02]/', $string)) {
    //pass
} else {
    //fail
}
```

Or possibly substitute `preg_match('/^[^lLvV02]+$/', $string)`.

Comment: Not what I was looking for, but nice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would probably be: `^[a-km-uw-zA-KM-UW-Z13-9]*$`.
I'm not saying that it's pretty but it does what it's supposed to.